# Copy few rows from one database to another

Tags: postgresql, replication, bulkcopy

I have two PostgreSQL databases on two different machines and the network connection is *slow*.
I would like to copy few selected rows from the first instance to the second. Unfortunately, the full dump of single table is too big. A CLI solution would be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are a few ways to do it without resorting to 3rd-party tools.

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.3, you can use the extension [postgres_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).

If you are using an older version of PostgreSQL have a look at [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)

If you want a command-line only solution, and you are using Linux (or Cygwin etc), you could try something like the following:

```
psql -d yourdb -qtAXc "COPY (select col1, col2, col3 from your_table where id between 123 and 456) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER" -U youruser -h localhost -p 5432 \
| psql -d yourremotedb -U youruser -h your_remote_host -qtAXc "COPY yourtable FROM STDIN CSV HEADER"
```